# How can I find overlapping objects on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, overlap

is there any easy way to find the objects ids that are overlapped?
Here's an example of the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random as rand


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master, width, height):
        self.master = master
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=width, height=height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.create_objects()

    def create_objects(self):
        r = 5
        for i in range(100):
            x = rand.uniform(0,1)*width
            y = rand.uniform(0,1)*height
            self.canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r, fill="red")

    def find_overlaps(self):
        pass


width = 800
height = 600

root = tk.Tk()
app = GUI(root, width, height)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like for the find_overlaps function to give me the pairs of the object ids that are overlapped (or tripplets if such case happen). Is there any easy/efficient way to do it?

Comment: I think it's not. If your objects are circles, you might like to use some extra calculations to define points that are close. Using KDTrees is quite a good approach in this case, check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps that is possible for you to do here:

1. Get the tuples of ids of objects you have created on `canvas`. You can do it using `canvas.find_all()` method.
2. Get coordinates of these objects using `canvas.coords(id)`.

I have checked out standard `find_overlapping` method of `canvas`. It helps to determine which object are overlapped with specific rectangle only and I guess you need to solve problem you mentioned using some mathematics with a help of this method. Although, I have found a nice alternative, not based on `find_overlapping`:

```
def find_overlaps(self):
    r = 5
    X = []
    tags = self.canvas.find_all() #finds tags of all the object created
    for tag in tags:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(tag) # corresponding coordinates
        center = [(x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2] #centers of objects
        X.append(center)

    tree = cKDTree(X)
    print(tree.query_pairs(2*r))
```

#### Output

This is a set of couples of tags:

```
{(2, 63), (10, 93), (70, 82), (8, 45)}
```

#### Note

`from scipy.spatial import cKDTree` is required

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this is what i needed. Which of the two methods do you think is best?

Comment: `find_overlapping` doesn't find result straightforwardly, you'll need to do the checkings for each rectangle on yourself. Another difference is that cKDTrees is precise only if objects are circles.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpfull, since my objects are circles i will use the cKDTrees approach then.